# Angular Material: Why is control coloring reversed?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've just installed material in a new project using `ng add @angular/material`. I added a test button to one of my components as described [here](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview):

```
  <button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

I imported added an import to app.module:

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

   

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My button, however, is displaying with the text in what I expected the background color to be and its background in what I expected its text color to be. I have blue text on a white background, which doesn't work. It seems like this should be working right out of the box. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

If you need more information, just say the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you've mentioned in your question that is the expected behaviour. I think the markup you might be looking for is:

`<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>`

or

`<button mat-flat-button color="primary">Primary</button>`

Comment: <forehead slap> Geez, you're right. I can't even call that a noob mistake. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No worries mate, happens to the best of us :D